# I've downloaded Multibit Bitcoin Client, but I don't know how to view what my wallet address is?

Tags: wallet, address, multibit

I am attemting to purchase some bitcoins with a cash deposit to my bank using this site: https://www.canadianbitcoins.com/index.php

The site requires me to validate my wallet address so they know where to deposit the bitcoins. I am very new at this and I don't know what my wallet address is. I don't even know if I have one yet, becuause all I have done is downloaded a bitcoin client (Multibit).

Answer (score 6):

Click 'Receiving', then look for an address.

[image: multibit ui]

Comment: I'm using Bitcoin Wallet 0.8 with a similar screen as above, I've got `Default` and `test` address labels configured, but they don't have the same address; why is that? I would think my Bitcoin Wallet address should be unique and consistent.

Comment: @SAFX Are you using MultiBit, or the bitcoin.org client?

Comment: The bitcoin.org client.

Comment: @SAFX [Ask your question separately then.](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)